# I'd like to know if this sentence is correct and what is the meaning?

Tags: phrase-meaning, phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrases

> I'll keep this thing up active.

I don't know if this is correct and what did you get from it? What's the idea of this sentence?

Comment: I have no idea. Where did you find it?

Comment: I was writing yesterday and this came to my mind. I wanted to give the idea of continuation like keeping it up. Would it be possible to say, for instance, keeping this up (keep this up)?

Is this too strange? What should I use instead of these words to give the same idea of continuation?

Comment: Out of context it is still difficult to understand. If it were a blog, I'd say:" I will update frequently/daily/weekly."

Comment: I think it would be better if you make *active* an adverb that modifies the action, if your meaning was to continue doing "this thing": "I'll *actively* keep this thing up." But your question would be better if you don't use vague terms like "thing". What those "things" are might be important in context. Otherwise, "I'll (actively) keep this up." is usually enough.

Comment: thanks for the replies. And the thing is a list, a work.
So, for instance, ''I'll actively keep this work up'' would be fine?

Comment: I will keep the (Name of list would be good) list updated bi-weekly/weekly/monthly/daily/ twice daily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are potentially missing two different sayings

> I'll keep this thing up.
>   I'll keep this thing active.

or

> I'll keep this thing up and active.

both can have the same meaning of "keeping things going".